# I have a problem with Instagram's embed.js

Tags: instagram, embed

when loading the embed.js from Instagram (https://www.instagram.com/embed.js) the returned redirect contains a strange redirect URL (duplicate //www.instagram.com). This only occurs if I'm working on a mobile network (tested with T-Mobile and Vodafone Germany). It's fine at home with the DSL line.

```
curl -v4 https://www.instagram.com/embed.js
*   Trying 31.13.92.174...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.instagram.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=CA; L=Menlo Park; O=Facebook, Inc.; CN=*.www.instagram.com
*  start date: May 27 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 25 12:00:00 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.instagram.com" matched cert's "www.instagram.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7f8fc2007a00)
> GET /embed.js HTTP/2
> Host: www.instagram.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 302
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< location: https://www.instagram.com//www.instagram.com/static/bundles/metro/EmbedSDK.js/43531caab721.js
< cache-control: max-age=21600
< date: Fri, 12 Jul 2019 07:52:30 GMT
< x-fb-trip-id: 1679558926
<
* Connection #0 to host www.instagram.com left intact
```

I tried different HTTP versions but that didn't help. I recognized it first in a browser where the Instagram embeds didn't work when loading the page from a mobile network.

I guess I'm doing something wrong when embedding Instagram but I think I implemented the embed according to their documentation.

Can someone give me a hint?

Many thanks!